# Conic section going through five points

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Let be $ v_1=(x_1,y_1),..., v_6=(x_6,y_6) $ six points on the affine level.

How can I show that there exists a conic section, which is going through $v_1,..,v_5 $ ?

The general equation for a conic section is $$ ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$
I don't have any idea for this proof.. so any ideas very welcome !

Comment: Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic

Comment: This may also be of interest: [5 points determine uniquely a conic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3435466/139123).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [5 points determine uniquely a conic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435466/5-points-determine-uniquely-a-conic)

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $a,b,c,d,e,f$ such that

$ a x_i^2 + b x_i y_i + c y_i^2 + d x_i + e y_i + f = 0 $ for $i = 1,2,3,4,5 $

In addition for a given point $(x,y)$ we want

$ a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + dx + ey + f = 0 $

Write these equations in the form

$ A \theta = 0 $

where $A$ is $ 6 \times 6 $ and whose first row is

$ [ x^2 , x y, y^2, x , y, 1 ]$

and $(i+1)$-th row is

$ [ x_i^2 , x_i y_i, y_i^2, x_i , y_i, 1 ]$

and $\theta = [a,b,c,d,e,f]^T $

This means (since $\theta $ is not identically zero), that matrix $A$ has to have a zero determinant.  Therefore, the equation of the conic is

$ | A | = 0 $

Note that the determinant of $A$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, as is evident by expanding the determinant about the first row.